# Mac OS X Finder and opening files in Firefox

Tags: macos, mac, firefox, finder

Whenever I click on file in Finder to be opened in Firefox, it opens it in new Firefox window instead of new tab in existing Firefox window. Can this behaviour be changed? Mac OS X 10.5.8, Firefox 3.5.3.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with the Finder.  Firefox decides how it handles new requests …

Comment: I played around with anything I found in about:config, but no luck (also using Firefox 3.5.3). So I'd think either you just can't change this, or it's bug in Firefox 3.5 like Nerdling suspected.

Answer (score 7):

Firefox [Preferences](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options+window+-+Tabs+panel?style_mode=inproduct) » Tabs » Open new windows in a new tab instead

Comment: Well, I have option "Open new windows in a new tab instead" checked — is this it? Anyway, it doesn’t do any difference.

Comment: Yep, like niksy said, that doesn't seem to affect opening files from Finder. Considering that, this answer seems overrated...

Comment: It causes new tabs for me: 10.6.1, 3.0.8.

This would have to be a bug in Firefox, check their bugzilla?
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

Even with that option checked, if you do not already have a window open, firefox will open a new window for each file you open. However, if you already have a window open, firefox will open a new tab for each file you open.

Answer (score 0):

try the [tab mix plus extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122). I believe it lets you choose what to do with links opened from other apps.